# Storing same name to database and to storage directory

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm having a hard time storing the same file name to my local storage and to the database when I save a file. As of now I'm storing the file upload using the `storeAs` function which I pass a name for the uploaded file but when I check my database, the name is different and it generates like `/tmp/phpGiNhTv`. How can I save file to database with the same name as to the file in my local storage?

Sample code:

```
public function store(Project $project)
    {
        $this->validate(request(),[
                'name' => 'required|min:8',
                'category' => 'required',
                'thumb' => 'required'
            ]);

        if( request()->hasFile('thumb') ) {
            $file = request()->file('thumb');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $destination = 'images/projects/';
            $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move($destination, $filename);
            $new_file = new Project();
            $new_file->thumb = $filename;
            $new_file->save();
        }

        Project::create(request()->all());
        return redirect('/projects');
    }
```

> Additionaly, This file upload contains other fields inside a form so
>   other fields also should save to database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use uniqueid() to get unique name for uploaded file and then concatenate with original extension of your file and then store it to the local storage and then to database.

```
if($request->hasFile('thumb')){
    $file = request()->file('thumb');
    $extension = file->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $destination = 'images/';
    $filename = uniqid() . '.' . $extension;
    $file->move($destination, $filename);

/*
 * To store in to database
 * you can use model of database and store in it.
 * Eg. File Model.
 */

$new_file = new File();
$new_file->filename = $filename;
$new_file->save();
}
```

Comment: Not working for me pal. it says `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::save()` .

Comment: I removed the last 3 lines and it saves the file but not same name in my database

Comment: What is your model name for the database table it should be File to work above code

Comment: Model name is `Project`. so it would be replaced to `Project` not File right?

Comment: It works mate! thanks but issue arises coz some other fields not included when saving to database. Please checkout the updated post above.

Comment: can you explain about other fields so that i can help

Comment: Please see my original post above, some fields are included upon saving the file. Right now it won't save coz some fields are missing. Thanks

Comment: name and category are required fields so validator returns the function.
If you fill those through form then save those data like this.

    $data = new Data();
    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->category = $request->category;
    $data->save();

Here Data is  database model where your form data is stored.

Comment: I get it now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if( request()->hasFile('thumb') ) {

    $file = request()->file('thumb');

    //Relative upload location (public folder)
    $upload_path = 'foo/bar/';

    //separete in an array with image name and extension
    $name = explode('.', $file->getClientOriginalName());

    //1 - sanitaze the image name
    //2 - add an unique id to avoid same name images
    //3 - put the image extension
    $imageName = str_slug($name[0]) . '_' . uniqid() . '.' . $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    //Here you have the upload relative path with the image name
    //Ex: image/catalog/your-file-name_21321312312.jpg
    $file_with_path = $upload_path . $imagename;

    //Move the tmp file to a permanent file
    $file->move(base_path() . $upload_path, $imageName);

    //Now you use the file_with_path to save in your DB
    //Example with Eloquent
    \App\Project::create([
        'name' => $imageName,
        'path' => $file_with_path
    ]);
}
```

If you are going to use the Eloquent example, remember to set the mass assignment variables in your model

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#mass-assignment

Comment: Thanks mate but not working in my end. `$imageName` is undefined variable.